# User available at times

Tags: website-design, usability, users, user-expectation, user-centered-design

I was looking trough some answers best practices on 'user availability' or whatever it's called.

Let's say I'm a user renting out or providing some kind of service. Let's assume this is my side job.

So my availability would be `weekends or holidays`. If I was doing something full time my availability could be `work days only` etc etc.

How would one represent that to user that it looks presentable and comprehensive. Is there a website that has these kind of availability. I think something like this is more simpler than date pickers/hours pickers etc. for this purpose only though.

Simple availability information without giving exact time.

Any thoughts?

**Question update (thanks 3nafish for good questions):**

1. Are you just asking for a way to specify a set of days recurring each week? 
   Yes this is exactly what I want. But not necessarily set of days, but rather group days into a group like weekdays instead of Saturday and Sunday. Want to simplify the user selection.
2. Or would people sometimes need to specify times combined with the days? I would stay away from specifying times, again it seems to complicated to gather that info from the user and I want user to provide as little input as possible. Selecting certain times can lead to all sort of problems which I'm trying to avoid by providing higher level selection groups like (workdays workhours, weekend night time , Holiday midday etc). I'm basically trying to think of the names of these higher level time groups.
3. Would the availability always be the same each week? - Yes

Comment: Welcome to the site, @Remember_me.  Can you provide some more context? Are you just asking for a way to specify a set of days recurring each week? Or would people sometimes need to specify times combined with the days? Would the availability always be the same each week?

Answer (score 1):

I think a calendar-like interface would work best here, very similar to Outlook or Google Calendar. It's great that you want to keep it simple and easy to use, so I would brainstorm something that reveals more options/complexity if the user wants to be more specific, but presents something very simple initially:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fClSl5.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Most users would only require weekly availability with one of the assumed time intervals. But as the second mockup shows, they could specify completely custom times or custom recurrence. I didn't mockup the Yearly one, but I was envisioning that being a full blown calendar with the current year where they could pick individual days (and that's where the "Holidays" quick-selection button would come into play).

I think no matter what widgets you go with, the summary label at the bottom is really helpful to the user (where their selection reads like a sentence) so they have the confidence your interface captured their intent.

Comment: P.S. As to coming up with the right "quick select" options for groups of days or time spans in the day, we would need a better understanding of the use of the problem domain/use of the site (for example a taxi service might have an emphasis on after-work hours but a conference calling service an emphasis on work hours)

Comment: hi @J.Dimeo thank you for your response. If you were building a dating website for instance. And you would want users to select roughly their availability. Then you would show those rough choices on their profile. So the other users browsing their profile know roughly when to contact them or meet with them. Of course meeting requires more specific time, but in order to plan specific time you know at least what are your options and in what timeframe you need to set the exact time. (I would take the exact time out of equation in this case. I was merely adding more context)

Comment: In that case, I might have a similar UI to the one I mocked up (definitely with fewer options if you think that's appropriate) for specifying availability, but display it as the single summary sentence to other users viewing the profile (i.e. "Available for meeting up on Weekends, Available for conversation on Weekdays in the evenings").

Comment: I'd like to see that similar UI if you have it thanks